# In MySQL Workbench, BLOB field, "Open Value in Editor", "Edit Data", is there a find feature?

Tags: database, search, find, blob, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench. A field in a table I am using is type BLOB. That field contains text data, which is sometimes quite long. To view this field, I right click on the field cell and select "Open Value in Editor". This produces a popup window named "Edit Data ..." which displays the contents of the field. Since the text is lengthy, I often need to search it to find a specific piece of data that is relevant to me. However, unlike a text editor, there doesnt appear to be a Find feature in this popup window. I attempt to use ctrl-F to activate a Find feature, and it does not work. I am not surprised, but yet I am disappointed. Instead, I am forced to copy the text and paste it into a text editor. From there I can use the text editor's Find feature to search the text.

I feel that this approach introduces too many intermediate steps if I have to do this often. Is there a better way to search within this popup window?

Is there a way to send a feature request to the makers of MySQL Workbench, to have a Find feature added to the BLOB field popup window? I noticed that you can search for bugs and enter a feature request here, but I dont have an oracle account: https://bugs.mysql.com/